# Why does the subject observer not update when inside a lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subject

In my angular application, I have an `app-routing` file with an `LayoutComponent` as path and my modules as `loadChildren: "./pages/home/home.module#HomeModule"`. Inside my home module I have home component where I have a loader `<app-loader></app-loader>`. The loader service has `isLoading` as a `Subject` which is set `true` or `false` in `show()` and `hide()` methods respectively before and after a request in a interceptor.

With the help of console log debugging I found that the show and hide methods are called successfully but the value is subject is not set properly due to which I an not able to see the loader. I tried registering `loader.servie` in Component's provider array but still no result

```
app-routing: 
             {
                path: "home",
                loadChildren: "./pages/home/home.module#HomeModule"
             },
home.module:
   providers: [
      LoaderService,
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
   ]

loader.service
export class LoaderService {
    isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
    show() {
        console.log('show');
        this.isLoading.next(true);
    }
    hide() {
        console.log('hide');
        this.isLoading.next(false);
    }
}
loading.interceptor.
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService, private adalService: AdalService) {

     }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.loaderService.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide())
        );
    }
}
loading.component.html
<div *ngIf="isLoading | async" class="overlay">
loading.component.ts
 isLoading: Subject<boolean> = this.loaderService.isLoading;
```

If I manually set isLoading to true inside loading.component then it shows the loader so clearly it is not getting set through the event emitter. Tried to replace Subject with BehaviourSubject but got no luck

Structure is somewhat like this:

```
    app.module
    |
   layout.component
        |
-----------------------------------
|            |         |    
feature1.module    home.module    feature2.module
                      |
                ----------------
                |       |
               loader.service  home.component.html
                                |
             <div showLoader>
```

Comment: please create the stackblitz sample app.

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved, following were the issues:

- There were multiple declaration of the services instead of single
  parent module.
- Subject was used instead of BehaviourSubject.

Comment: *BehaviorSubject (Unable to edit the answer to make 1 char change)